# Read attachment name from bounced mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read the name of the attachment from the bounced mails. Here is one way I was able to get it but i want to know if there is a better way to do it. This is quite time consuming.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(message.getContent().toString()));
while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
    index = str.indexOf("filename");
    if(index >-1){
        filename = str.substring(index+9); 
        if (filename.length() > 0) System.out.println("Attachment  : " + filename);
    }
}
```

Below is the complete code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

public class CheckingMail {

    public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user, String password) 
    {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.put("mail.imap.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
            properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");

            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");

            store.connect(host, user, password);

            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            System.out.println("emailFolder.hasNewMessages()---" + emailFolder.hasNewMessages());
            System.out.println("emailFolder.getNewMessageCount---" + emailFolder.getNewMessageCount());
            System.out.println("emailFolder.getUnreadMessageCount---" + emailFolder.getUnreadMessageCount());


            Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.RECENT), false)); 
            System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
            int bcnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                if(message.getFrom()[0].toString().contains("MAILER-DAEMON")){
                    bcnt++;
                }
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);

                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int index = -1;
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(message.getContent().toString()));
                String str = "" , filename = "";

                while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
                    index = str.indexOf("filename");
                    if(index >-1){
                        filename = str.substring(index+9); 
                        if (filename.length() > 0) System.out.println("Attachment  : " + filename);
                    }
                }
                System.out.printf("Time : %d%n", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);

                for(int j=0;j<message.getAllRecipients().length; j++){
                    System.out.println("Recipients "+j+" : " + message.getAllRecipients()[j]);
                }
                System.out.println("Date: " + message.getSentDate());
            }
            System.out.println("Bounce count : " + bcnt);
            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = "imap.mail.yahoo.com";
        String mailStoreType = "imap";
        String username = "yourmail@yahoo.com";
        String password = "*****";

        check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

    }

}
```

The Example mail

```
Sorry, we were unable to deliver your message to the following address.

<bounce@yahoo.fhdf>:
No MX or A records for yahoo.fhdf

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.

Received: from [ip] with NNFMP; 02 Jul 2015 07:26:24 -0000
Received: from [ip] with NNFMP; 02 Jul 2015 07:23:24 -0000
Received: from [ip] with NNFMP; 02 Jul 2015 07:23:21 -0000
Received: from [ip] with NNFMP; 02 Jul 2015 07:23:21 -0000
Received: from [] with NNFMP; 02 Jul 2015 07:23:21 -0000
X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-4
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 413220.37634.bm@omp1027.mail.ir2.yahoo.com
X-YMail-OSG: ByrxKJsVM1ngLTK9ms.eLuFTCEl6w0XU0HtbGqwE70HR4CtF8BU_giAhODvLvMc
NiITUbpoTi2nhfKQ0WnxsPY4KMJyCRONlErkMhBA8a_bi7HLGeUqj53lPEgJ9oZtyTxykF4OVqw8
e3Y0LO_rgeE49pQzvjFDNmE7L3kAePyzTbWfPv7Vper3tC8kWTTU21W5POlCB7LQ38FJoMsGOtSq
qRjYLEILpy6xk34mPTwiSXkIb8iU.--
Received: by 217.12.9.9; Thu, 02 Jul 2015 07:23:21 +0000 
Date: Thu, 2 Jul 2015 07:23:20 +0000 (UTC)
From: test <fromuserid@yahoo.com>
Reply-To: test <fromuserid@yahoo.com>
To: "bounce@yahoo.fhdf" <bounce@yahoo.fhdf>
Message-ID: <443022398.1267465.1435821801286.JavaMail.yahoo@mail.yahoo.com>
Subject: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_1267464_969780179.1435821801286"
Content-Length: 293584

------=_Part_1267464_969780179.1435821801286
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_1267463_786603392.1435821801283"

------=_Part_1267463_786603392.1435821801283
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



------=_Part_1267463_786603392.1435821801283
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><body><div style="color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, Sans-Serif;font-size:16px"><div id="yui_3_16_0_1_1435820944162_7576"><br></div></div></body></html>
------=_Part_1267463_786603392.1435821801283--

------=_Part_1267464_969780179.1435821801286
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=img-211134632-0001.pdf
Content-ID: <c95faa3b-7ec0-2555-6b65-cdab3f05aabb@yahoo.com>

JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRvciAoWGVyb3ggV29ya0NlbnRyZSA1MjMw
```

Comment: An example of such a bounced mail would be helpful.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have added an example bounced mail

Comment: I think the main problem with your method is its lack of reliability - the mail could contain the word "filename" unrelated to an attachment. If all bounced messages are like the example, I'd probably remove all the lines up to the embedded copy, then parsed it as a message and handled that. It would be more reliable, though not necessarily more efficient. But not all bounces look the same or even give you a full copy of the message.

Comment: @RealSkeptic By embedded copy do you mean the actual mail body?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#bounce), there's a standard for such bounced messages, but not all servers implement the standard.  You've found one such server.  The FAQ has other pointers that might help, but you're pretty much stuck with heuristics.  If you frequently use a particular mail server that doesn't support the standard, you could make your heuristics smarter and more reliable by recognizing bounced messages from such servers.

For example, in your example bounced message above, the entire original MIME content of the message seems to be included.  You could extract just that part and use the [MimeMessage constructor](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#MimeMessage-javax.mail.Session-java.io.InputStream-) to parse it and more easily extract the filename.

Comment: Did you mean something like this
`InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getContent().toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(emailSession, stream);`

Is there any other way to read attachment name and other details from the bounced mail. As you said not all servers implement the standard for bounce mail some don't even have the name of the attachment in the body.

Comment: Yes, sort of like that, but you have to strip off the stuff at the beginning before the MIME content of the included message.  Are there other ways to do this?  Certainly.  This is software.  There's always another way.  But as I said, they're not so much algorithms with predictable results as they are heuristics that will work sometimes and fail sometimes.  You have to decide what sorts of failures you're willing to tolerate and create heuristics for the cases you care about.